# How to create jpa query to update any(param) field to any(param) value?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I am trying to create a JPA query to update filed for the value - both field name and value are params.

like

```
@Query("UPDATE tableName SET :field = :value WHERE id IN (:idList)")
```

but getting validation fail oon start.
Is it possible to construct such query with JPA?

Comment: Why not just pass in an object with the changes? Even if you can do this, I wouldn't; what stops someone mistakenly 'update employee set salary = 0'? That IN clause takes in ids is an awful lot of potential failure.  Otherwise, look at JPA criteria queries, which you can build on the fly from parameters programatically and are going to give you better errors if the properties/fields don't exist or match up with the value types. Criteria queries would let you pass in a map of property/value pairs to build the query with how ever you might need.

Comment: @Cris selection of field names is fetch from db, so can't be mistaken, all other mistakes - on users (admin level) conscience, who is properly alerted, and can revert actually last changes, i will save prev list

If i do that with object changes - i can think only about ugly `switch (fieldNme) case address -  for(id : idlist) object getById; object.setAdress(); object save();`
And it will be about 15 fields - so 15 hardcoded switch cases.